# php email form function

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

can you help me with the following lines ?

I'm new to php and I want to send my form data via php to my mail.
This script is working but not all the data is transferring .

This is the form -

```html
<form id="contact" method="post" action="mail.php">
  <h1></h1>
  <div id="formContainer">
    <div class="ChangeColor">
        <label> </label>
        <input oninput="validation(this)" id="text1" name="1" type="text" tabindex="1" placeholder="">
        <div class="eror">*</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ChangeColor">
        <label> </label>
        <input id="text2" type="text" oninput="mailValidation(this)" tabindex="2" name="2" placeholder="">
        <div class="eror">*</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ChangeColor">
        <label> </label>
        <input id="text3" oninput="validation(this)" type="text" name="3" tabindex="3" placeholder="">
        <div class="eror">*</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>  </label>
        <textarea id="text" tabindex="4" name="4"> </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="MyBut" disabled="true">
</form>
```

this is the php

```php
<?php
$email_to= "ksmail@gmail.com" ;
$email_subject=$_POST['3'];
$email_message=$_POST['4'];
$email_head = $_POST['2'];
$email_name = $_POST['1'];
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_name ,$email_message);
echo "mail sent!"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$email_name` from the mail function call

```
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message);
```

From the [mail PHP documentation](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Perhaps you're meant to change your code to:

```
 <?php
    $email_to= "example@example.com" ;
    $email_name = $_POST['1'];
    $email_subject=$_POST['3'];
    $email_message=$email_name. PHP_EOL . $_POST['4'];
    $email_head = $_POST['2'];

    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message);
    echo "mail sent!"
    ?>
```

Comment: The code in the answer adds $email_name to the message `$email_message=$email_name. PHP_EOL . $_POST['4'];`